# Crawling simple web site at certain depth by Scrapy

Tags: web-crawler, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to **scrape** a 3-depth web site about some problems and answers. It has a simple structure like the following:

- 2nd depth -> contain **meta** data (problems description)
- 3rd depth -> contain **actual** data (problems and answers)

  ```
    /prob
      +-> /prob/problemLists.html
        +-> /prob/problem123456.html
  ```

I wrote Scrapy code like the following, using `response.meta['depth']` as condition.

Are there any better ways to do that?

```
class DmzSpider(CrawlSpider):
    rules = (
         Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(deny=('index\.htm',callback='parse_list'))),
    )

    def parse_list(self, response):
        if response.meta['depth'] == 2:
        # Scrape descriptions ...
        return items

        elif response.meta['depth'] ==3:
            parse_item(response)
        
    def parse_item(self, response):
        # Parse items and save it according to prob_id...

        return items
```

Also I have tried the 3 following options, noone of them worked and the request_depth_max=1 at summary:

1. Adding:
   from scrapy.conf import settings
   settings.overrides['DEPTH_LIMIT'] = 2
   to spider file
2. running the command line with -s option:
   /usr/bin/scrapy crawl -s DEPTH_LIMIT=2 mininova.org
3. Adding to settings.py and scrapy.cfg:
   DEPTH_LIMIT=2

How should it be configured to more than 1?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for, however: You can set a depth limit using the DepthLimitMiddleware which is enabled by default. For its settings see: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#module-scrapy.contrib.spidermiddleware.depth

Comment: What I want is to crawl the pages at 2nd and 3rd depth. No deeper. I'll edit my questions to make it clearer.

Comment: FYI It’s __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraper__, __scraped__) not scrap

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [depth limit](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#depth-limit) to 3 in this case, see the [settings page in Scrapy documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html)

Comment: Where can I find the settings file ?